# Using MySQL user defined variables to store data

Tags: mysql, variables, max, min

I have following MySQL query that returns results as required.

However, I would also like to get **Min and Max** of the **Price** coloumn either stored in User Defined Variables (tried with not luck) or some in other way.

So that I could retrieve min and max values of price coloumn **along with total results Count** by executing second query.

*Kindly note this query takes considerable time to execute (fetching more than  100K records), hence would not like to execute it second time by any chance.*

Could someone guide me as how can this be achieved ?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM (
    ( SELECT 
        `id`, `code`, `name`, `price`,
        MATCH (`code`,`type`,`name`,`keywords`,`categories`)
        AGAINST ('+term*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `relevance`
    FROM `ps_search__tableA`
    WHERE
        ( MATCH (`code`,`type`,`name`,`keywords`,`categories`)
        AGAINST ('+term*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
        AND `type` REGEXP '.*' )
union all
    ( SELECT
        `id`, `code`, `name`, `price`, 
        MATCH (`code`,`type`,`name`,`keywords`,`categories`)
        AGAINST ('+term*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `relevance`
    FROM `ps_search__tableB`
    WHERE
        ( MATCH (`code`,`type`,`name`,`keywords`,`categories`)
        AGAINST ('+term*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
        AND `type` REGEXP '.*' )
) AS `tblsearch`
ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
LIMIT 0, 36
```

and I access its Count by

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

Comment: OMG. First of all, you should use database *columns and rows* to store your data, not *user defined variables*. Second, it seems like you only use full-text search is some weird ways. If you want to make it work fast, you should rethink your approach, or hire someone who could.

Comment: @mvp, first could you guide me as how could i store the min and max value from this query in DB, as I am using this query's results in PHP.

and second I assume I am using full text search in correct manner, unless you could point me at somewhere (url, guide, book) showing a correct approach to use full text.